# Help developing a module for managing unzipped files

Tags: files

I have a content type called resources and one of the fields is a file field where users can upload content such as a pdf, video, docx, swf etc...

What I am trying to do is allow user to upload a zip file and unpack it on the server then let the user select the main file to be displayed.

So for example if someone had a swf file which has videos they can upload the zip then the server will unzip the files and the user can select the swf file as the main file to display.

I have managed to build a module to unzip the file on hook_node_submit, but not sure how to progress this to get the required functionality as explained above.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest having the unzipping occur as part of the AJAX upload - that way, the form can be modified on the fly to include file names in a select box for example, which the user could then select. This keeps it to a one-step process, rather than adding another step after saving

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, do you know which hook I would need to have the unzip happen on upload?

Comment: off hand, no I dont, that's not something I've ever had to do. If there isn't something already available, you could rewrite (create a custom version) of the file upload widget to include the desired effect